# Java's equivalence to the Python's recv() network function

Tags: java, python, network-programming

I have a client implemented in Java, and a server implemented in client. 
The client sends a message (string) such as "nesting:1:2" to the server, the server decodes the meaning of the input to create and send back binary data to the client.

This is the Python server code.

```
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # self.data has the data

        (name, index, n) = self.data.split(":")
        m = int(n)
        i = int(index)
        size = sizes.sizes[name][i]

        # creates the binary data
        bf = [0x41] * size * m      
        key = ''.join(chr(x) for x in bf)
        self.request.send(key) #

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    PORT = 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

The client Python code is as follows:

```
af, socktype, proto. canonname, sa = res
s = socket(af, socktype, proto)
s.connect(sa)
s.sendall('nostring:1:5')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

I tried to find the equivalent to the `s.recv()` method, I found `read()` method. So, I tried this method where `byte[] buffer = new byte[157*10];` is declared outside the method.

```
public byte[] receive() throws IOException {
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    in.read(buffer);
    in.close();
    socket.close();
    return this.buffer;
}
```

The issue is that the `in.read(buffer)` never returns until the server disconnects.

What might be wrong? This is the full source code for the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try, but to my mind, the socket should not be closed between the send and receive action, one socket means one connection to the server. 
The python server will most likely try to answer on the given socket, which will be closed, and the java client will wait on another.

Try something like that: creating the socket in the constructor and closing it at the end of the receive (if you are sure you might call the send/receive pair only one time)

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class GpcSocket {
  private Socket socket;
  // default value
  private int SERVER_PORT = 9999;
  private String SERVER_IP = "192.168.3.100";
  OutputStream out = null;
  InputStream in = null;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[157*10];

  public GpcSocket(String serverIP, int serverPort) {
    this.SERVER_PORT = serverPort;
    this.SERVER_IP = serverIP;
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
  }

  public int send(byte[] str) throws IOException {
    out = socket.getOutputStream();
    out.write(str);
    out.flush();
    // out.close();
    return str.length;
  }

  public byte[] receive() throws IOException {
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    in.read(buffer);
    in.close();
    socket.close()
    return this.buffer;
  }
}
```

Comment: out.close() will cause Exception of socket closed.